# github automatically adds group to every new repository

Tags: github

i've an issue in my organization, whenever new repository is created one of groups is added automatically to that repository with read permissions. It cannot be removed from there even with organization owner privillages. It states that this is Managed by organization owners but no setting like this is visible either in that group nor in organization settings.

Any ideas how to change that/remove that "automation" without deleting this group from organization ?

Checked settings of both group and organization.

Comment: Hello ! I am interested in knowing how to setup such an automation. Do you know if your GH organization is managed using Terraform ?

Answer (score 2):

in the Organization settings, there is a section under "Security" for "Code security and analysis".  If you configure a team as a "Security manager", that team is granted a minimum of read-access to all repos in the org.  Remove the team from that setting and you will be able to remove it from Collaborator list on repos. here is [GH documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/organizations/managing-peoples-access-to-your-organization-with-roles/managing-security-managers-in-your-organization#removing-the-security-manager-role-from-a-team-in-your-organization)